# How to Set date pattern in jquery datepicker

Tags: c#, jquery, datetime, datepicker, cultureinfo

I have converted the datetime format based on client region.
I have done it with below code using c#

```
   public CultureInfo GetDateFormat()
   {
       var _CultureInfo = new CultureInfo(1043);
       return _CultureInfo;
   }

   public string GetFormattedDateString(string _DateToFormat)
   {
       string _tempDate = string.Empty;

       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_DateToFormat))
       {
           _tempDate = DateTime.Parse(_DateToFormat).ToString(GetDateFormat().DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
       }
       return _tempDate;
   }
```

this works fine. But if I use the same approach in jQuery datepicker it gives a different format.

Ex: In `c#`

> 10-10-2015

in `jquery`

> 10/10/2015

Below is the code for jQuery format change,

```
public string GetDateFormat()
{
    var pattern = new CultureInfo(1043).DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;

    return pattern;
}

@Html.DatePicker(new { 
                    name = "filter.StartDate", 
                    value = Model.Filter.StartDate, 
                    data_bind = "value: StartDate", 
                    data_datepicker_options = "{dateFormat: '" + GetDateFormat() + "'}" 
})
```

above is the razor code which creates the date picker.

Is there a way to get same date format in c# and datepicker output?

Comment: Have you tried explicit  `dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' ` ?

Answer (score 0):

In your datepicker you could add this

```
dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yyyy'
```

to change the format

or in your model you could add this

```
 [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
```

on top of it

-See also this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx). Its very useful for dateformats in razor.

Comment: Actually I cant hard code the format as you mentioned because the format might change according to user culture. I am getting the user culture when logging process and change the date format accordingly.